# Counterpart to anonymous interface implementations in C#

Tags: java, c#, code-translation

I'm working on translating some code from Java to C# but am having some trouble, maybe someone out there can help?

I have problems trying to replicate anonymous interface implementations that are widely used in Java, but have no idea how to.

An example is:

```
List<DATA> queue1 = new ArrayList<DATA>(dataSet);
            // Sort by distance to the first promoted data
            Collections.sort(queue1, new Comparator<DATA>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(DATA data1, DATA data2) {
                    double distance1 = distanceFunction.calculate(data1, promoted.first);
                    double distance2 = distanceFunction.calculate(data2, promoted.first);
                    return Double.compare(distance1, distance2);
                }
            });
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried?
2) What is promoted.first?
3) What are you trying to do in this code?

Comment: One substantial difference is that *classes* are anonymous in Java, but *methods* are anonymous in C#. The answers below are good - just keep in mind that if you see Java code implementing an interface with more than one member, it's up to you whether the corresponding anonymous methods (i.e., delegates) are in the same class or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have problems trying to replicate the inline functions that are widely used in Java

These are not inline functions, that's anonymous classes implementing a specific interface.

C# provides *delegates* that you can define inline or in a separate function.

Here is an example of sorting a `List<DATA>` in place using the `Comparison<T>` delegate:

```
List<DATA> queue = new List<DATA>();
queue.Sort(
    (left, right) => {
        double distance1 = distanceFunction.Calculate(left, promoted.first);
        double distance2 = distanceFunction.Calculate(right, promoted.first);
        return Double.Compare(distance1, distance2);
    }
);
```

Note that in order for this to work, the `distanceFunction` variable needs to be in scope at the spot where you invoke `queue.Sort`. It can be a local variable defined above the invocation point, or a member variable/property of the class enclosing the function that makes the call.

Comment: +1. It's also worth noting that C# doesn't allow for non-static inner classes either, for the same reasons it doesn't allow for anonymous classes.

Comment: @Brian: What do you mean with "non-static inner classes" not being allowed? The following is valid code: `public class Outer { private class Inner { } }`

Comment: But `Inner` is always static in C#. That is, it doesn't have an implicit reference to `Outer`. The reference has to be explicitly specified via a field in the inner class. In fact, the implicit reference in Java in non-static inner classes and anonymous classes is often the source of memory leaks in Java code.

Comment: @Brian: Inner is not a static class. You can instantiate it. But I understand what you mean.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ah, a difference in semantics then. By static I meant in reference to the class declaration, not its methods. What I meant is `private class Inner` in C# is the same as `private static class Inner` in Java. In any case, still a good answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth What Java calls a *static inner class* and what C# calls a *static class* are two very different things: in C# you can instantiate only non-static classes, and IIRC nested classes cannot be static at all. In Java, static member classes are identical to C#'s nested classes, while non-static member classes retain a reference to the object inside of which they were instantiated. There is no analog in C#, but you can easily emulate it by keeping a reference to `Outer` instance inside the `Inner` object, and setting the reference to `Outer` in the `Inner`'s constructor.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks a lot, yes, the distanceFunction is within the scope. the problem I get now is that there seems to be no double.Compare (or I haven't found it). I've tried distance1.CompareTo(distance2) but it's not allowed within the sort.

Comment: @mauriciod73 I'm sorry, it should be `Double.compare`, not `double.compare`. Here is [a link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks a lot, I was wondering if you could please help me, I still have some troubles converting part of the application to C# and I'm really lost, could I contact you please? I don't want to use automatic converters or IKVM becouse it needs to be en C#... Thanks

Comment: @mauriciod73 The best thing is to post more questions on Stack Overflow. The site does not like the idea of members contacting each other ([see this answer on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/175984)), and I definitely have no time for it. But there's lots of people here who are ready to help you solve whatever issues that you might have. P.S. I agree, I'd stay away from automated converters.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you end up using delegates instead of interfaces in may cases, especially in cases like this where it's likely the caller will want to define the method inline.  You can use a lambda to define an anonymous method inline where any delegate is expected.

```
List<String> list = new List<String> { "B", "D", "E" };

list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

There is no equivalent to Java's anonymous interface implementations in C#, so if there is an interface required (which isn't the case for sorting a `List`) you'll need to create a named class to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

C# uses the concept of delegates in the place of anonymous interface implementations.

Assuming you've replaced `ArrayList<DATA>` with the .Net `List<DATA>`:

```
IEnumerable<DATA> sorted =
    queue1.OrderBy(q => distanceFunction.calculate(q, promoted.first));
```

Answer (score 0):

assume that you have an a List of Data objects in c#:

```
queue1.OrderBy(a => distanceFunction.Calculate(a, promoted.First));
```

Comment: Note that here you aren't mutating the list, you're creating a new collection based on the previous one.  You would need to use `List.Sort` to mutate the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that parallels the original Java, then:

```
internal virtual void test()
{
    List<int> queue1 = new List<int>(dataSet);
    queue1.Sort(new ComparatorAnonymousInnerClassHelper());
}

private class ComparatorAnonymousInnerClassHelper : IComparer<int>
{
    public virtual int compare(int data1, int data2)
    {
        double distance1 = distanceFunction.calculate(data1, promoted.first);
        double distance2 = distanceFunction.calculate(data2, promoted.first);
        return distance1.CompareTo(distance2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the C# equivalent.  Why do you feel that it needs to be called 'anonymous'?

Comment: There is no exact C# equivalent; there is no mechanism in C# for creating anonymous interface implementations.  The closest mechanism, that is the mechanism generally used in place of that the OP is using in Java, is anonymous methods, rather than named interface implementations.

Comment: If you try it out, you'll see that it works identically - this just explicitly does what Java does behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  The question is how to create anonymous interface implementations.  The answer to that question is, "It's not possible in C#".  As for what mechanism is usually used in place of that mechanism, throughout the framework, it is not explicit interface implementations.  Most comparable locations where you would expect an anonymous interface implementation in Java it will accept a delegate in C#, commonly implemented with an anonymous method. While it doesn't result in quite the same implementation as in Java, it's the preferable coding technique to solve that same problem.

Comment: Yes - I agree.  However, I look at it from a code conversion perspective - given an anonymous interface implementation in Java, the most pain-free way of getting the same result in C# is making the hidden implementing class non-anonymous.